# Grails dynamic url rewriting

Tags: grails, url-rewriting, url-mapping

I am trying to rewrite my urls for a particular controller (and action) for example:

```
www.mysite.com/user/search?sex=male&from_age=18&to_age=19
```

would become

```
www.mysite.com/user/search/sex/male/from_age/18/to_age/19
```

I know I could do this using Grails' url rewriting along the lines of:

```
"/user/search/sex/$Sex/from_age/$from_age/to_age/$to_age" {
  controller = 'user'
  action = 'search'
}
```

The problem I face is that a user could just as easily trigger a url like:

```
www.mysite.com/user/search/sex/male/to_age/19/location/chicago
```

i.e. the url is dynamic based on the search criteria entered by the user in the search form

Is there anyway of dynamically rewriting the urls along the lines of Apache's `mod_rewrite` so I could have `param_name/param_value` instead of `?param_name=param_value`?

Comment: `from_age` in url mapping won't match with `to_age` string used in sample url. User wont get anything.

Comment: Yes that's my point, I need to find a way of creating the mapping dynamically so foo/bar becomes ?foo=bar regardless of what foo or bar are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map a wildcard url to your search action, but you will have to perform the parsing of the parameters yourself:

UrlMappings.groovy:

```
"/user/search/$query**" {
    controller = 'user'
    action = 'search'
}
```

This would give you everything after the static portion of the url as a single string.

i.e. `www.mysite.com/user/search/sex/male/to_age/19/location/chicago` would give you `params.query = 'sex/male/to_age/19/location/chicago'`

However, these kind of urls don't participate in dynamic url rewriting, so you would have to build the urls yourself when attempting to link to it.

quick unsafe (unescaped) example of transforming a paramMap into that style of query string:

```
def queryStr = params.collect({ n,v -> "$n/$v" }).join('/')
g.createLinkTo(controller: 'user', action: 'search', params: [query: queryStr])
```